# Correos personalizados en Laravel

Tags: laravel, email, contraseña, registro

Quiero crear una aplicación con Laravel 5.8 con resgistro de usuarios. Lo que quiero es que en el momento de registrarse un usuario, o de pedir su contraseña olvidada, se le envíe un correo personalizado, no los que envía Laravel por defecto (por ejemplo, con un logo de la aplicación en el propio correo, un saludo personalizado, etc).
Sé que tendría que tener una carpeta con los emails, pero no sé como hacer que Laravel envíe mis emails, en lugar de los que vienen con la aplicación por defecto.
Así que la pregunta es sencilla ¿Cómo hago que, en el momento de registrarse un usuario se le envíe MI correo de verificación, en vez de el estándar? ¿Cómo hago que cuando un usuario pide un enlace de cambio de contraseña se le envíe MI correo diseñado para ello?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para [personalizar](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passwords#password-customization) el email de cambio de contraseña, debes crear una [Notificacion](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/notifications#mail-notifications), para que posterior a ello sobreescribas el método `sendPasswordResetNotification()` dentro de tu modelo `User`.

Primero creas la notificación:

```
php artisan make:notification MyCustomResetPassword
```

Luego sobreescribes el método con la notificación que creaste.

```
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
    $this->notify(new MyCustomResetPassword($token));
}
```

Para la verificación de email al registrarse es un procedimiento similar, sólo que ahora debes sobreescribir el método `sendEmailVerificationNotification()`

```
public function sendEmailVerificationNotification()
{
    $this->notify(new MyCustomEmailVerification);
}
```

Por otro lado, si no quieres crear notificaciones personalizadas y simplemente quieres modificar las que laravel trae por defecto, puedes publicar los archivos:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-notifications
```

Y hacer las modificaciones en los archivos `resources/views/vendor/notifications`